# Разбор предложения по составу.

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, синтаксический-разбор

Правильно ли здесь расставлены запятые?
"Вдруг я услышала, что ключ поворачивается в замке, подумала, что Рома что-то забыл(,) и поспешила к двери".

Подлежащее и сказуемые - Я услышала, подумала и поспешила. Следовательно после забыл (перед "и") запятая не нужна. Или ею выделяется придаточное предложение? Забыла со школы...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Верно, придаточное предложение.